# Show that $f(x)<1$ for a special $x$

Tags: inequality, hyperbolic-functions, constants, bernoulli-numbers

Let define the function :

$$f\left(x\right)=\frac{2}{x\left(\tanh\left(xe^{-1}\right)+1\right)}$$

---

---

Show that :

$$f\left(\frac{1+\sqrt{3}}{2}\right)<1$$

---

---

Some facts :

$$\tanh(x)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{2^{2n}(2^{2n-1}-1)B_{2n}z^{2n-1}}{(2n)!}$$

Where $B_{2n}$ ar the Bernoulli's numbers

The solution of :

$$f(x)=1$$

Can be find using the Lambert's function .

The function $f(x)$ is clearly decreasing on $(0,\infty)$

Question :

How to show the claim by hand without calculator ?

Comment: Excuse me but I don't get the question. Just substitute $x = \dfrac{1 + \sqrt{3}}{2}$ into $f(x)$ and calculate it.

Comment: See the edit :)!

Comment: @Turing I did not downvote you.

Comment: @RiverLi I never said that! But I am rather familiar with this site, and often there are ghosts who downvote at random, without any specific reason. Never thought about you (it wouldn't make sense, also because you gave an excellent answer, and I don't think you're interested in downvoting other answers, unless they are wrong or useless) ^^

Comment: @Turing You are kind. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Some thoughts**:

*Note*: $\tanh y = \frac{\mathrm{e}^y - \mathrm{e}^{-y}}{\mathrm{e}^y + \mathrm{e}^{-y}}$.

Denote $a = \frac{1 + \sqrt3}{2}$.
It suffices to prove that
$$a(\tanh(a\mathrm{e}^{-1}) + 1) > 2$$
or
$$a\left(\frac{\mathrm{e}^{a \mathrm{e}^{-1}} - \mathrm{e}^{-a\mathrm{e}^{-1}}}{\mathrm{e}^{a\mathrm{e}^{-1}} + \mathrm{e}^{-a\mathrm{e}^{-1}}} + 1\right) > 2$$
or
$$\mathrm{e}^{a \mathrm{e}^{-1}} > \frac{1}{\sqrt{a - 1}}$$
or
$$\mathrm{e}^{-1} > \frac{1}{2a}\ln\frac{1}{a - 1}$$
or (using $\frac{1}{a - 1} = 2a$)
$$\frac{\ln \mathrm{e}}{\mathrm{e}} > \frac{\ln(1 + \sqrt3)}{1 + \sqrt{3}}.$$

Let $f(x) = \frac{\ln x}{x}$.
We have $f'(x) = \frac{1 - \ln x}{x^2}$.
Thus, $f(x)$ is strictly decreasing on $[\mathrm{e}, \infty)$.
It suffices to prove that
$$\mathrm{e} < 1 + \sqrt3.$$